# Difficulty calling my controller in my index

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm having trouble refactoring a code with express, I'm new to this development

```
//index.js

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const connection = require('./config/database')

const User = require('./models/User')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

connection
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Conexão feita com o banco de dados')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Rodando')
})

app.post('/createUser', {...})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Rodando')
})
```

Below is my controller, where I create my user

```
//userController.js

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = () => {
    const obterHash = (password, callback) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, nul, (err, hash) => callback(hash))
        })
    }

    const save = (req, res) => {
        obterHash(req.body.password, hash => {
            const password = hash

            User.create({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: password
            }).then(() => {
                res.status(202)
            }).catch(() => {
                res.status(404)
            })
        })
    }

    return { save }
}
```

I want to use this controller of mine in my index.
If anyone has an example on how to refactor this code

I don't have in mind how to call this controller in my index

Comment: Just import it using ```require``` and use it in your routes,
```const usersController = require('/pathto/usercontroller.js')```

Comment: Give me an example please, because I had done this before and the request does not load

Comment: I found you did return only save function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is like your code:
Your controller:

```js
module.exports = () => {
  const x=(a)=>a*a;

  return {x}
}
```

your main code:

```js
const c = require('./controller.js');

console.log(c().x(2)); // will print out 4
```

Comment: Did you check how my controller is doing?

Comment: You did ask how to use it,

Comment: it is better to use ```classes``` when there is huge controller methods.

Comment: I just asked how to use it, I appreciate the effort, but your answer didn’t solve

Comment: @RuanDuarte I did update the answer, i hope it helps you to understand how to use.